# Usage of "across"

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis

Does this sentence make sense?

"Each transaction generates a huge amount of data **across** the supply chain"

I'm writing a statement of purpose and want to convey that a large amount of data is captured at different points in the supply chain, whenever a business transaction is made. Does the word "across" suit the context?

Comment: If I get your intended meaning, I'd consider using "throughout" instead of "across".  Though neither is completely satisfying.

Comment: *"across" the supply chain* looks completely satisfying to me. It means that a lot of data is generated at every major and minor nodes in the Supply Chain Network. If I were you, I'd stick to "across".

Comment: @BiscuitBoy now I'm confused. Does across sound okay?

Comment: @manoj - Yes. For instance, "Company CX registers growth *across* verticals, geographies". It implies that Company X grew in most of / all of the business verticals and business centers (locations)

Comment: It's idiomatic, but to someone not involved in supply chain management, it might read funny. *Generates* doesn't naturally collocate with *across*. We tend to expect a verb of motion like *travel* or *flood*.

Answer (score 1):

What about 'at each point of the supply chain' or even 'at different (or many) points of the supply chain', as you wrote in your explanation? 'Across' sounds somewhat vague to me.

Comment: at different points of the supply chain looks good. I will use this. Thanks.